# continuity of a piece wise defined function

Tags: calculus

Let
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} x & x \in (-\infty, a) \\ x^2 & x \in [a, \infty) \end{cases}
$$

If $f(2) = 4$, what is the range of values of $a$?

can we assume continuity between $0$ and $2$?

Comment: Sorry to roll back the edit but did the people look carefully at what the editor did? I don't think they did, so I have rolled it back.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
Assuming you want $f$ to be continuous first we need to make sure that at $x = a$ both the left hand and the right hand limits agree. That is we need to make sure $a = a^2$. From here you should be able to get a possible list of $a$ that work. Next ensure that $f(2) = 4$ for each of these $a$ and you have your answer.